# How to scroll to a certain element in dojo contentPane programatically

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I have a ul list of 100+ `li` elements displayed inside `dojo.contentPane` which is displayed in a custom dialog which extends dojo dialog. When this `contentPane` is rendered, I would like scroll bar to automatically slide to nth `li` element. How can I do that?

I have seen an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/6aNrp/ where scrolling happens on click of a button, but I would like the same behaviour automatically during rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in the onLoad event of your content pane :

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("myContentPane"), "onLoad", function(evt){
    // your code here
});
```